# WSO2 Identity Server - How to add parameters to the state parameter in the callback

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-identity-server

Context: using openid connect with WSO2 IS 5.1.0

We've implemented a custom authentication endpoint for our products. So a typical flow would be:

GET to https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize 
Returns 302 to https://authenticationEndpoint.local/login which returns a page with User,password and remember me checkbox. To this endpoint a parameter for *state* is filled with values that we want to get back in the query parameter when the callback gets called.
(The state parameter contains the status of the *rememberMe* checkbox in the application)

the correct values are posted to https://localhost:9443/commonauth in which, if we want the remember me option to be checked there must be a parameter for chkrememberMe="on". So far so good, the cookie *commonAuthId* gets created with the correct expiration date.

Now when https://application.local/Account/ExternalLoginCallback gets called the state is exactly how we previously set it which is a problem if i only clicked the *rememberMe* checkbox in the authenticationEndpoint page, because now the rememberMe would be false and it was previously set.

Question:
How can i modify the *state* parameter in the authenticationEndpoint application? Or alternatively get the remember Me value from the callback in the application? (Could not find any endpoint in the *oauth2* api that could do this)

### [image]

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more details about the  https://application.local/Account/ExternalLoginCallback that you have mentioned and how it is related in the context?

Comment: it's just a fairly standard callback action in my AccountController. It's the least important part of my issue i think. What i'm really wondering is how to manipulate the state from the custom authentication application. It's the one i created to replace login.do by setting the application-authentication.xml file with something like this:
<AuthenticationEndpointURL>https://authendpoint.local.co.uk/Auth/Login</AuthenticationEndpointURL>